# Place combobox on a frame of a ttk::notebook

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to put a combobox over a frame of a tk notebook. I arrange the frame and the components using grid. When i place the combobox over the frame, the frame in the background disappears. What can be the reason for this? My code is as follows:

```
ttk::notebook .f.n  -width 1600 -height 800
frame .f.n.f1
frame .f.n.f2 
.n add .f.n.f1 -text "TabOne" 
.n add .f.n.f2 -text "TabTwo"
grid .f.n -sticky news -row 0 -column 0
#Code to create a side menu
 grid [frame .f.n.TabOne.m -width 200 -height 800] -sticky news -row 0 -column 0
 grid [ttk::combobox .f.n.Tabone.m.d -values {"val 1" "val 2"}] -sticky news
```

Comment: When I run your code I get:Error in startup script: bad window path name ".f"
    while executing
"ttk::notebook .f.n  -width 1600 -height 800"
    (file "foo.tcl" line 1)

Comment: f is frame in the window on which the notebook n is placed. This is just a part of the code. You can add a frame f before that.

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example, per the usual conventions of SO. Please don't make answering the question harder for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To put a combobox within a tab's pane, you have to make it a child of the widget (usually a frame — and definitely so in your case — but not necessarily) that is the interior of the tab. Otherwise it is not *inside*, but rather just *stacked on top*.

The easiest way of getting this consistently right is to build widget names from variables that reference their parents. Idiomatically, you store the name returned by the widget construction function and then build the child names by simple concatenation, like this:

```
set nb [ttk::notebook .f.n -width 1600 -height 800]
set tab_one [frame $nb.f1]
set tab_two [frame $nb.f2]
$nb add $tab_one -text "TabOne" 
$nb add $tab_two -text "TabTwo"
grid $nb -sticky news -row 0 -column 0

#Code to create a side menu
grid [frame $tab_one.m -width 200 -height 800] -sticky news -row 0 -column 0
grid [ttk::combobox $tab_one.m.d -values {"val 1" "val 2"}] -sticky news
```

Comment: The tab labels themselves are not their own widgets, but rather just things drawn by the `ttk::notebook` instance itself. Content managed by the notebook needs to be a child of the notebook.